# AngularJS $http, CORS and http authentication

Tags: angularjs, cors

Because using CORS and http authentication with AngularJS can be tricky I edited the question to share one learned lesson. First I want to thank igorzg. His answer helped me a lot. The scenario is the following: You want to send POST request to a different domain with AngularJS $http service. There are several tricky things to be aware of when getting AngularJS and the server setup.

First: 
In your application config you must allow cross domain call

```
/**
 *  Cors usage example. 
 *  @author Georgi Naumov
 *  gonaumov@gmail.com for contacts and 
 *  suggestions. 
 **/ 
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    //Enable cross domain calls
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
});
```

Second:
You must specify withCredentials: true and username and password into 
request.

```
 /**
  *  Cors usage example. 
  *  @author Georgi Naumov
  *  gonaumov@gmail.com for contacts and 
  *  suggestions. 
  **/ 
   $http({
        url: 'url of remote service',
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic bashe64usename:password'
        }
    });
```

Тhird:
 Server setup. You must provide:

```
/**
 *  Cors usage example. 
 *  @author Georgi Naumov
 *  gonaumov@gmail.com for contacts and 
 *  suggestions. 
 **/ 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://url.com:8080");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
```

For every request. When you receive OPTION you must pass:

```
/**
 *  Cors usage example. 
 *  @author Georgi Naumov
 *  gonaumov@gmail.com for contacts and 
 *  suggestions. 
 **/ 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
   header( "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" );
   exit();
}
```

HTTP authentication and everything else comes after that.

Here is complete example of usage of server side with php.

```
<?php
/**
 *  Cors usage example. 
 *  @author Georgi Naumov
 *  gonaumov@gmail.com for contacts and 
 *  suggestions. 
 **/ 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://url:8080");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
   header( "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" );
   exit();
}


$realm = 'Restricted area';

$password = 'somepassword';

$users = array('someusername' => $password);


if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) == false ||  isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) == false) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');

    die('Not authorised');
}

if (isset($users[$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']]) && $users[$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']] == $password) 
{
    header( "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" );
    echo 'You are logged in!' ;
    exit();
}
?>
```

There is an article on my blog about this issue which can be seen [here](http://georgi-naumov.blogspot.com/2014/02/angularjs-http-cors-and-http.html).

Comment: The question is edited.

Comment: I'm a little confused, it's angularjs but you have it wrapped in PHP tags....did I miss something?

Comment: This is just a example of server side logic. Text below "Тhird: Server setup" is server side logic.

Comment: @onaclov2000 AngularJS is for the client side. This can talk to any server side, PHP, Ruby, Perl, Python, Java, JavaScript... I could go on..

Comment: Is this a question? It is more like a good answer :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No you don't have to put credentials, You have to put headers on client side eg:

```
 $http({
        url: 'url of service',
        method: "POST",
        data: {test :  name },
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
    });
```

And and on server side you have to put headers to this is example for nodejs:

```
/**
 * On all requests add headers
 */
app.all('*', function(req, res,next) {


    /**
     * Response settings
     * @type {Object}
     */
    var responseSettings = {
        "AccessControlAllowOrigin": req.headers.origin,
        "AccessControlAllowHeaders": "Content-Type,X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5,  Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name",
        "AccessControlAllowMethods": "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
        "AccessControlAllowCredentials": true
    };

    /**
     * Headers
     */
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", responseSettings.AccessControlAllowCredentials);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",  responseSettings.AccessControlAllowOrigin);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", (req.headers['access-control-request-headers']) ? req.headers['access-control-request-headers'] : "x-requested-with");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", (req.headers['access-control-request-method']) ? req.headers['access-control-request-method'] : responseSettings.AccessControlAllowMethods);

    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    }
    else {
        next();
    }


});
```

Comment: with CORS in general, does the server have to allow **all** headers (Content, Content-Length, Referer, etc...) present in the real, i.e. non-OPTIONS, request?

Comment: @KevinMeredith No you don't have to allow all headers, you can allow only what you need and you can even limit also to one domain.

Comment: how do I know what I need?

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer :)

Comment: I am confused, why do I not need to authenticate with the endpoint if it's secured by an http basic authentication?

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Comment: When I am trying to implement the above code, I am getting following error:

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Answer (score 3):

For making a CORS request one must add headers to the request along with the same he needs to check of mode_header is enabled in Apache.

For enabling headers in Ubuntu:

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

For php server to accept request from different origin use:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
```