# http get angular returns nothing

Tags: angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a login for an ionic (angular) application, and I'd like to use http get. However, it appears to return nothing..

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope','md5', function($scope, $http, md5, $state) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.login = function() {

    var pass = md5.createHash($scope.data.password || '');

    $http.get("http://<link>.com")
        .then(function(response){ $scope.field = response.data; });

    }
}])
```

$scope.field is just a textfield in the html page.
But it just stays blank, whatever the http link is..

edit: and yeah, the pass and credentials aren't used yet, since I first want http get to return something.

Comment: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issue?

Comment: Yeah maybe, but when I use ajax it does return the html >>>>

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "link..",
data: "some data",
success: function(html){  
   return html;
....

Comment: I found the solution in another post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455045/angularjs-http-cors-and-http-authentication