# AngularJS/Spring MVC, HttpSession not persistent

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, session

We are developing a web application, we're using `Spring MVC` (along with `Spring Boot` and `Spring Security`) and `AngularJS`.
Therefore, we have two distinct servers running for the application.

We are trying to store the user session backend, to ensure a proper level of security, so we tried to use the `HttpSession`object, but every time we want to retrieve the existing session, a new instance is created (we've checked the session ids).

Here's what we're doing to login :

```
$scope.authenticate = function () {

  var postObject = new Object();
  postObject.mail = $scope.userName;
  postObject.password = $scope.userPassword;

  $http({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/login",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: postObject,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }).success(function successCallback(response, status) {
      if (status == 200) {
        $scope.messageAuth = "Login successful"
        $scope.go('/services');
      }
    })
    .error(function errorCallback(error, status) {
        $scope.messageAuth = "Error " + response;
    });
};
```

Then, we check the credentials, if they are correct, we store the user information into a new session :

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

@Resource
UserService userService;

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<User> loginSubmit(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
    if (isAuthorized(user)) {
        User authenticatedUser = this.userService.getUserByMail(user.getMail());
        authenticatedUser.setPassword(null);

        session.invalidate();
        HttpSession newSession = request.getSession(true);
        newSession.setAttribute("USER_ROLE", authenticatedUser.getRole());

        System.out.println("/login : SESSION ID = " + newSession.getId());
        System.out.println("/login : " + newSession.getAttribute("USER_ROLE"));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticatedUser);
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                .body(null);
    }
}

@RequestMapping("/user")
public String user(Principal user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println("/user : SESSION ID = " + session.getId());
    System.out.println("/user : " + (String) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("USER_ROLE"));
    return (String) session.getAttribute("USER_ROLE");
}
```

And finally, from the Angular app, we'd like to get the user information by calling `/user` like this :

```
var f = function() {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/user').success(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }).error(function() {
      console.log('error');
    })
};
```

We've already tried pretty much every we found about how to manage a session with Spring Security, maybe the problem comes from the Angular part?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks in advance

Comment: You aren't using Spring Security you are actually working around it...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and you think it is part of the problem?
We should be able to use `HttpSession` anyway, right?

Comment: If you use Spring Security and use the defaults `/login` is intercepted by Spring Security and your controller doesn't do anything. There should be nothing preventing you from using a `HttpSession` (we use a similar setup on my current project).

Comment: I tried to change `/login`by `/authent`, same result.
It doesn't seem to be related to Spring Security, because when I disable it, the problem persists (still new instances of `HttpSession`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the solution, we just needed to add a few config lines in our app.js file :

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

More information here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455045/angularjs-http-cors-and-http-authentication?rq=1)

Hopefully it will help someone, someday!