# How to solve ASP.NET Web API CORS Preflight issue when using PUT and DELETE requests with multiple origins?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors, preflight, http-options-method

I have an ASP.NET web API that is being called by three different SPA. I am using windows authentication for the web API. I initially tried to configure CORS in the Web.config like this:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:63342" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This caused this preflight issue:

```
Response to preflight request doesn’t pass access control check: No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource. Origin (...) is therefore not allowed access.
```

that I solved by adding the following method in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

This approach worked perfectly for a single SPA. I thought that I could go to the Web.config and add the other origins like this:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:63342,http://localhost:63347,http://localhost:63345/>
```

but apparently that is not allowed. This produced the following error:

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values (...), but only one is allowed. Origin (...) is therefore not allowed access.
```

So in order to try and fix this, I changed my approach and instead decided to try to configure CORS on the WebAPIConfig.cs, in the Register method like this:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:63342,http://localhost:63347,http://localhost:63345", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
cors.SupportsCredentials = true;
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

I thought this would work but now I have the preflight error again when using PUT and DELETE requests and I don't know how to fix this. I debugged the Application_BeginRequest method and it is still flushing the OPTIONS request so I have no idea of what is causing this error. Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

EDIT:

The print of the preflight error:

[image]

Comment: @Aravind I'm sorry I can't really understand the solution you suggested because SO doubles the quotes for some reason. Could you please write it in another manner somehow?

Comment: You can allow all domains and methods by using `new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*");`  Better way to handle this is to create your own custom attribute using ICorsPolicyProvider and implementing GetCorsPolicyAsync method.

Comment: @Paresh But I can't use the * because I'm using windows authentication and it is incompatible. Besides that I only want to allow those three urls.

Comment: use * for the headers and methods and let the url be as it. new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:63342, http://localhost:63347, http://localhost:63345","*","*");

Comment: @Aravind I tried it but it didn't work. Still getting the preflight error.

Comment: did you try adding the EnableCorsAttribute in controller or a particular method by annotating them there?

Comment: @Aravind I tried adding it just now. I specified only one origin to see if the problem would go away but I'm still getting the preflight error.

Comment: please add a screenshot of what error you get ! to try out some other alternative option as none of the available ones are not working!

Comment: @Aravind I added it to the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by further customizing the Application_BeginRequest method in Global.asax.cs, like this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Request.Headers.GetValues("Origin")[0]);
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

What this code does is add the missing headers to the OPTIONS response (preflight request) that were causing the preflight error. Since I have different origins calling my web API, I'm using `Request.Headers.GetValues("Origin")[0])` to set the origin in the response dinamically.

In the WebApiConfig.cs I still specified the different origins but used wildcards on the headers and methods, as well as setting the `SupportsCredentials` to true, like this:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:63342,http://localhost:63347,http://localhost:63345", "*", "*");
cors.SupportsCredentials = true;
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Also, if you're using AngularJS like I am, you must configure $http to use credentials. This can be configured globally like this:

```
angular
.module('Application')
.config(['$httpProvider',
    function config($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    }
]);
```

And that's it. This solved my problem. If someone else is still having problems, I  recommend reading the following publications, which helped me reach my answer:

- http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api
- https://evolpin.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/the-cors/
- [AngularJS $http, CORS and http authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455045/angularjs-http-cors-and-http-authentication)
- [AngularJS performs an OPTIONS HTTP request for a cross-origin resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource)
- [AngularJS POST Fails: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660712/angularjs-post-fails-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404)

Answer (score 2):

Create custom attribute using `ICorsPolicyProvider` something like following to check if the requested origin is allowed or not

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method,AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class EnableCorsForAPIKeysAttribute :
      Attribute, ICorsPolicyProvider, IFilter
    {
        public async Task<CorsPolicy> GetCorsPolicyAsync(
          HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var corsRequestContext = request.GetCorsRequestContext();
            var originRequested = corsRequestContext.Origin;
            if (await IsValidOrigin(originRequested)) //Check if requested origin is valid or not
            {
                // Grant CORS request
                var policy = new CorsPolicy
                {
                    AllowAnyHeader = true,
                    AllowAnyMethod = true
                };
                policy.Origins.Add(originRequested);
                return policy;
            }
            else
            {
                // Reject CORS request
                return null;
            }
        }

        public bool AllowMultiple { get {return false;} }
    }
```

To use it, add it to your API controller

```
[EnableCorsForAPIKeys]
public class APIBaseController : ApiController
{
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this solution make me have to add that annotation to all the controllers? I would rather have a solution where I can configure everything globally.

Comment: I think you can do it at the global level using `config.Filters.Add(new EnableCorsForAPIKeysAttribute());`