# Uncaught TypeError: app.all is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a very simple angular page here

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <p>Today's welcome message is:</p>
  <h1>{{myData}}</h1>

</div>

<script>

  var app = angular.module('corsApp', []);

  app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

  }

  ]);


  // Added all header request and response.
  app.all('/*', function (request, response, next) {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
    next();
  });



  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("welcome.htm")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    });
});


</script>
```

---

I kept getting this in my console.

**Uncaught TypeError: app.all is not a function**

How do I prevent that ?

I'm following this :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21455819/4480164

Comment: app.all is middleware for nodejs (server-side javascript). It is not valid for angularJS in the client. The answer you are referencing states that plainly.

Comment: you are mixing server side and client side code. What server side language are you using?

Comment: just get rid of `app.all` since it doesn't appear you are working cross domain anyway

Comment: I'm trying everything I could to avoid the cors error. I just want to make a GET to this URL via angular : http://d.biossusa.com/api/distributor?key=bunlongheng

Comment: @charlietfl : The entire block of app.all = ?

Comment: You are misunderstanding how CORS works...those headers must be set by the api you are calling. If they are not set then you can see if api supports jsonp , if not you need to use a proxy on your server to get the data

Comment: You mean by the server ? I need to configure it in my Nginx server right ? if I use nginx as my web server ?

Comment: Yes...if it is your server you are getting data from

Comment: Yes. My server query data from database and return those data in JSON format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pointing this out because I cannot comment due to low rep, but you are also calling `ng-app="myApp"` which is looking for a module call for `myApp` and you do not have a module call for `myApp` so your controller will not fire correctly either maybe re-word your `myApp` to `app`?

Comment: What my code should look like to make it run without console error ?

Comment: you're calling `ng-app="myApp"` in your html, but you declared your module as `var app = angular.module()`, change the value in ng-app to `ng-app="app"` because your controller is looking for the module call and because you set that call to app.controller.... and you're call myApp in your html you're html is not going to fire correctly

Comment: `<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">` to `<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">` no where in your script did you declare the app module as myApp

Comment: You seem to know a lot about Angular JS. Do you anything about angular CORS error prevention ? Do you mind help me looking into this error that I am trying so hard to bypass it ? Here = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032996/angularjs-http-cors-get-nginx