# Getting JIRA filter results in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, cors, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to follow [AngularJS $http, CORS and http authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455045/angularjs-http-cors-and-http-authentication) to get filter results from JIRA and I can't make it work.

If I use the `GET` method,  the console reports:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://.../rest/api/2/search?jql=filter=28203.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Even though I've set `useXDomain`.

If I use the `JSONP` method, my success callback never gets invoked.  I've tried `.success`, `.then`, and `JSON_CALLBACK` and none work.  While `JSONP` isn't suppose to work at all in modern JIRA, I can see a successful response with the expected data in Chrome's Developer Tools' network work tab but the console reports:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://.../rest/api/2/search?jql=filter=28203' because its MIME type
>   ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking
>   is enabled.

My code -- based on that from the CORS question above -- is at https://plnkr.co/edit/IO4air3eN2vDoaOXJous?p=preview

What am I missing?

Comment: Wonder if you’re hitting this bug: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-59101 from the recent comments it’s not clear that bug has actually been fixed

Comment: See also https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Enable-CORS-in-JIRA-REST-API/qaq-p/553997#M115161